# Loss is not changing. Its remaining constant

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, loss-function

My Loss is constant after training an LSTM Model for the yahoo dataset of GE https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GE/history. Can someone help me out?

This is the code that I implemented

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import LSTM, Input, Dropout, Dense, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
import seaborn as sns
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

dataframe = pd.read_csv("DataSets/GE.csv") 

df = dataframe[['Date', 'Close']]
df.loc[:, 'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
sns.lineplot(x=df['Date'], y=df['Close'])

train = df.loc[df['Date'] <= pd.to_datetime('2017-12-31')]  # Corrected date for train
test = df.loc[df['Date'] > pd.to_datetime('2017-12-31')]

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler = scaler.fit(train[['Close']])

train.iloc[:, train.columns.get_loc('Close')] = scaler.transform(train[['Close']])
test.iloc[:, test.columns.get_loc('Close')] = scaler.transform(test[['Close']])

seq_size = 30

def to_sequences(x, y, seq_size_func=1):
    x_values = []
    y_values = []

    for i in range(len(x)-seq_size_func):
        #print(i)
        x_values.append(x.iloc[i:(i+seq_size_func)].values)
        y_values.append(y.iloc[i+seq_size_func])
        
    return np.array(x_values), np.array(y_values)

trainX, trainY = to_sequences(train[['Close']], train['Close'], seq_size)
testX, testY = to_sequences(test[['Close']], test['Close'], seq_size)

input_shape = (trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])
def build_model(learning_rate=0.001):
    model_f = Sequential()
    model_f.add(Input(shape=input_shape))
    model_f.add(LSTM(128))
    model_f.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
    
    model_f.add(RepeatVector(trainX.shape[1]))
    
    model_f.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
    model_f.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
    model_f.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(trainX.shape[2])))
    
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)  # Pass learning_rate to optimizer
    model_f.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mae')
    return model_f

model = build_model(desired_learning_rate)
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=5, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1)

plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation loss')
plt.legend()
```

Epoch 1/5
396/396 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 23s 47ms/step - loss: 0.1633 - val_loss: 0.3750
Epoch 2/5
396/396 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 19s 48ms/step - loss: 0.1661 - val_loss: 0.3752
Epoch 3/5
396/396 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 18s 45ms/step - loss: 0.1681 - val_loss: 0.3578
Epoch 4/5
396/396 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.1644 - val_loss: 0.3724
Epoch 5/5
396/396 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 21s 52ms/step - loss: 0.1663 - val_loss: 0.3817

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBAQV.png)

Comment: Could you provide one or two rows from the input file that generates de data frame to be able to understand how the data is being considered?